# Visual Studio docker support doesn't work with CI/CD

Tags: visual-studio, docker, continuous-integration

I have a solution that has the following projects:

- ServiceStackDockerTest
- ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceModel
- ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceInterface

When I add docker support inside visual studio this is the docker file that is added.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ServiceStackDockerTest/ServiceStackDockerTest.csproj ServiceStackDockerTest/
COPY ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceModel/ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceModel.csproj ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceModel/
COPY ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceInterface/ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceInterface.csproj ServiceStackDockerTest.ServiceInterface/
RUN dotnet restore ServiceStackDockerTest/ServiceStackDockerTest.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/ServiceStackDockerTest
RUN dotnet build ServiceStackDockerTest.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ServiceStackDockerTest.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ServiceStackDockerTest.dll"]
```

It adds the docker file inside the startup project (`/ServiceStackDockerTest`).

This works perfectly fine inside visual studio.  The image builds and runs when I debug and my breakpoints are hit.

However when I try to build this image normally using docker it doesn't work as it cannot find the path of the .csproj files.

I think this happens because Visual Studio is using volume sharing so it has access to the parent folders or it is changing the scope the Dockerfile is run in somehow.

However, in my CI pipeline it runs `docker build` on `ServiceStackDockerTest/Dockerfile` which copies this folder to docker and does not have access to it's parent folders.  The paths in VS dockerfile are all from the parent directory to where the docker file is located.

Why has Microsoft built in their support like this?  Surely building the dockerfile inside a CI pipeline is a common task.

What is the best way to fix this so I still can debug inside the container with live reload inside Visual Studio but also build the image in my CI pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this is actually very simple.  In CI pipeline just change the build context to the parent folder.

To build locally run this from parent folder `docker build -f SSDockerTest2\Dockerfile .` and then it runs it in context of parent direcory.